# Changing a file type html to jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am creating a chat application.

In my code I try to change the file `chat.html` into `chat.jsp`.

It creates an error and download that page.

```js
server.route([
      { method: 'GET', path: '/', handler: { file: "chat.html" } },
```

Comment: **it create a error** What error ? And it download what page ? Please provide more information

Comment: it downloads chat.jsp page in the name of download.if it is a chat.html page, it displays a chat page.but if it is chat .jsp it downloads the chat.jsp page

Comment: Well, said like that this seems to be what you want but I will guess that you receive the full chat.jsp (not compiled). Are you running this in local (without your app server ?) What are you using to insert the request's response. Did you debug anything ? You still give us not enough information ... Edit your question and add everything that could help us to understand ... From now, you've just let us the key of your car without telling us where it is parked and what is the problem with it...